# Seeming conflict between arrayfun and string()

Tags: matlab

I am hoping to be able to conveniently make sure a field of a structure array contain only strings (and not character arrays). For example,

```
S(1).f='abc'; S(2).f='asdfa'; S(3).f="aegwer";
```

If one does

```
setfield(S(1),'f',string(S(1).f))
```

`S(1).f` will be successfully converted to `"abc"` as expected.

However,

```
arrayfun(@(s)setfield(s,'f',string(s.f)),S)
```

not only fails to set all field values under 'f' to strings but actually convert all field values under 'f' to character arrays.

Why does `arrayfun` make `string()` into `char()`? Or is it something else?

MATLAB version I am using: R2018a

Comment: Did you mean `arrayfun(@(s)setfield(s,'f',string(s.f)), S)`?

Comment: Using Troy's correction I've been able to run your code, but I get the expected output. I'm using MATLAB R2017a.

Comment: Did you redefine `string`? Maybe created a variable with that name?

Comment: Please explain **clearly** what the end result of this exercise is. Are you trying to flush out a MATLAB bug? Are you looking for an explanation of some MATLAB behavior? Are you simply looking for a way to "normalize" your `struct`? Check out `controllib.internal.util.hString2Char` which is mentioned in [this blog post](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/string-char-compatibility). One can easily modify it to perform the opposite operation (char->string).

Comment: @TroyHaskin: Yes. That was a typo when creating the post. (Not in the example I tried in Matlab myself.) Thanks

Comment: @CrisLuengo: `string` is not redefined. I tried to make a separate minimum example in a clean workspace and got the same issue in my actual program. Also `string()` does work as intended without `arrayfun`.

Comment: @Dev-iL: My question arose from a need to "normalize" my `struct`. If there is no easy way to do it with `arrayfun` because there is a consistent bug in Matlab, I will just avoid it in this context. For an answer, it'd be nice if someone can explain why the unexpected results will consistently occur.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I still get the same result. I'll post the screen outputs to my question.

Comment: Are you storing the output from `arrayfun`, or is it just getting stuck in the default variable `ans`? `S` isn't actually changed by `arrayfun(@(s)setfield(s,'f',string(s.f)),S)`. I tried it in R2018a and it works fine.

Comment: I've just tried it on MATLAB R2019a, and also get the right output. Either this is a bug  specific to R2018a, or you have redefined `string` in some way. I lean towards the latter explanation.

Comment: @gnovice: I thought `setfield` changes the `struct` without creating an extra copy. As well, back in R2013a, I found copying `struct` is by reference. Does `setfield` store results by creating an extra copy by value?

Comment: Your anonymous function gets `s` by copy. You modify `s` and return it. `arrayfun` creates a new output array that collects the outputs of your anonymous function.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: actually, I neglected to check the class of `S(1).f` after using `setfield` without `arrayfun`. `setfield` doesn't seem to change the original `struct` for me. Is that supposed to be the case? That's not what I gather from the documentation.

Comment: Yes, check gnovice's answer below. MATLAB functions never change their input (unless the input is a handle class). In MATLAB you *always* do `a = func(a)` if you want to modify `a`.

Comment: Alright. Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that [`setfield`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setfield.html) and [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) do not modify the original object `S` (i.e. there is no reference-like behavior for structures). They create a new modified object and return it. You would have to overwrite `S` with this returned value for it to be updated:

```
S = arrayfun(@(s) setfield(s, 'f', string(s.f)), S);
```