# Matlab Pass By Reference by Class Wrapping

Tags: matlab

I have read many articles over the internet regarding pass by value vs pass by reference semantics of Matlab. In general the default behaviour is pass by value but with behind the scene optimizations.

My scenario is as follows. I have a function that performs a dynamic programming task. For this reason at the beginning of the function I am allocating huge buffer areas and at the end I am returning these buffers as solutions. My problem is that this function is invoked repeteadly and I am trying to avoid recreating the buffers.

A simplified example:

```
function [X,Y,Z] = my_filter(A,B,C)
    [dim1, dim2] = size(A);
    X = zeros(dim1,dim2); %huge buffers
    Y = zeros(dim1,dim2); %they don't need to be initialized with 0
    Z = zeros(dim1,dim2); %I just need to preallocate memory
    % do other things with buffers
end

for i = 1 : very many
   [X,Y,Z]=my_filter(A(:,:,i),B(:,:,i),C(:,:,i))
   %do other things with X,Y,Z
end
```

Of course I can pass X,Y,Z as input to the function to use behind the scenes in place optimization. However this makes function signatures very cluttered as I actually have a lot of such buffers.

My question is can I turn this into a class to make it more clean? For example:

```
classdef MyBuffer
properties
    X
    Y
    Z
end
methods
    function this = MyBuffer()
       %allocate buffers
    end
    function this = my_filter(this,A,B,C)
       %code here
    end

end
```

1) Is this a good approach?

2) Does the class need to subclass "handle"?

3) Do I get a performance hit by making buffers class properties?

Thanks

Comment: You need to profile your full code to understand where is the performance impacted. The real difference is going to come from what you do in `% do other things with buffers`. If they are lengthy operations, the cost of reallocating 3 arrays at the beginning of each loop is not going to be very significant. Even If they are already pre-allocated at the start of one loop iteration, if you have to zero them after the previous iteration, that's as bad as recreating them from scratch ... so it all depends on what you plan to do with these arrays ...

Comment: If each iteration needs a _fresh_ set of arrays, all pre initialised to 0 or other values, passing by reference or by value is not your actual problem. Reserving a permanent area of memory for these arrays (thanks to a class wrapping) is only going to be useful **if (and only if)** the next iteration need to reuse the `[X,Y,Z]` results of the previous iteration ... only in this case _passing by reference_ would save you a few arrays copies.

Comment: @Hoki As I wrote in the question buffers don't need to be reinitialized. Dynamic programming is an iterative algorithm. You only need to initialize the first element in the buffer the rest is based on one previous element. Those buffers are really big. I just don't want to have worse performance due to Object Orientation that will wipe up the gains from caching the buffer. That's why I am asking before even attempting to redesign the whole thing.

Comment: ok but then in your top code (not the class code) this is not what is happening. You are creating and zeroing these arrays at each iteration. I don't see the code reusing previous iteration results ... It would need to have `[X,Y,Z]` as _input_ for that ...

Comment: @Hoki. I don't need to reuse results from previous function calls. I haven't written anything like that anywhere.

Comment: Then back to my first comment, the critical part is how long `% do other things with buffers` will take. Using POO in matlab suffer a minor performance hit (when done properly, can be worse if messed up), and pre-allocation is also a minor hit. Either could be negligible compared to what else the code has to do. You need to test and profile the complete codes.

Comment: Ok then please tell me this will matlab do multiple in place optimizations if I change the signature to [X,Y,Z] = my_filter(A,B,C,X,Y,Z) and supply the buffers externally without even getting into Object Orientation?

Comment: As an advice, if you go for the class version, make sure the function which runs the long loop (`for i = 1 : very many`) is inside the class. Having to call the class repeatedly from outside will multiply the class perf hit by your number of iterations...

Comment: @Hoki No that needs to be outside of the class. I need to call obj.my_filter many times wih different parameters. Those parameters are not available to the class.

Comment: I am not privy to all the details of how MATLAB optimises in place modifications. I would try `[X,Y,Z] = my_filter(A,B,C,X,Y,Z)`, or even `[X,Y,Z] = my_filter(X,Y,Z,A,B,C)` and then **profile**. The profiler (or some good code timing) is the only thing that can give you a definite answer ...

Comment: If you call the function as `[X,Y,Z] = my_filter(A,B,C,X,Y,Z)`, and declare it with `function [X,Y,Z] = my_filter(A,B,C,X,Y,Z)`, then any changes made to `X`, `Y` and `Z` inside the function will happen in-place, the matrices will not be duplicated. This is fairly easy to verify. However, I don't see why creating these large matrices would be all that time consuming. As long as they fit in RAM, creating these should be nearly instantaneous. You should probably focus your time on other aspects of your program.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solves your problem (as Hoki pointed out, the problem is most likely the computation, not the allocation), but if you use the following class:

```
classdef MyBuffer < handle
    properties
        X
        Y
        Z
    end

    methods
        function self = MyBuffer(A,B,C)
            % Since your call to myfilter always contains A(:,:,i) ...
            % I guess that the first two dimensions of A, B and C are
            % required for allocation

            % Allocate X,Y and Z
            self.X = zeros(size(A,1), size(A,2));
            self.Y = zeros(size(B,1), size(B,2));
            self.Z = zeros(size(C,1), size(C,2));
        end

        function [X,Y,Z] = my_filter(A, B, C)
            % do something with you data
            X = self.X;
            Y = self.Y;
            Z = self.Z;
        end
    end
end
```

And then initiate it with

```
mybuffer = MyBuffer(A,B,C)
```

and call the filter as

```
for i = 1 : very many
   [X,Y,Z]= mybuffer.my_filter(A(:,:,i),B(:,:,i),C(:,:,i))
   %do other things with X,Y,Z
end
```

the allocation only happens once.

Comment: yes but why are you returning X,Y,Z from that function? After my_filter finishes they are available as object properties i.e mybuffer.X, mybuffer.Y. Is this faster? Any why did you subclass handle?

Comment: Why don't you simply test whether it is faster?

Comment: Because it is a very complex code and refactoring it will take a week. I am just asking about your experience before attempting this refactor. The buffers are very large. I simplified the problem dramatically. Those buffers are multidimensional and not the size of A for example. What about the handle?

Comment: Maybe you over-simplified the problem?! I agree with Hoki that you should analyze your code and find out what slows it down, then reduce your code to that part and ask how to improve it. If this takes you a week, it might be worth cleaning the code anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I made a small test. Actually allocating buffers beforehand saved 10% execution time. Not a big bang, but considering that this thing runs for days it is something for me. Profiler identified other stuff but those cannot be reduced without sacrificing arithmetic accuracy.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that if I don't subclass handle it becomes awfully slow to run the object function. Why is this happening?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure in this case, but in value classes, `self.X` in method `a` is not the same as `self.X` in method `b`. Thus, multiple copies exist which might slow down the code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you presented in your question alone, there is no advantage in using a custom-defined class. You should consider the actual data structure -- programming some things in java if necessary -- based on what you do, which you haven't really showed.

For the other concerns you asked about:

1) You don't need to rewrite the `dim`s. You can do `zeroes(size(A))`.

2) You don't have to create zero matrices either if it concerns you. You can create [empty matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/empty.html) in Matlab. Although the syntax is not as convenient.

3)

> Does the class need to subclass "handle"?

I don't see why you need your class to be subclass of `handle`. You didn't mention any need for event programming.

Having said that, being a subclass of `handle` means the object can be modified in-place as it is passed from function to function. I am not sure how reliable this is. See [this mathwork blog](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/03/22/in-place-operations-on-data/) for details.

4)

> Do I get a performance hit by making buffers class properties?

Are you worried that Matlab's JIT optimizations wouldn't cover lines using class objects? That really depends on what you. You have to test to find out.

5) Pass by value vs pass by reference

Struct fields and class properties should be pass by reference. At the same time, be careful that many built-in functions do not modify the original fields of struct. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56721078/seeming-conflict-between-arrayfun-and-string) for two examples.

`format debug` may help you inspect whether two fields/properties point to the same memory address. Although the debug format is undocumented. So reliability is of question.